# Sonar plugin only for verifying modified file

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

I am working on java-maven based project and I configured sonar in my application.When I run sonar, It check all the application but I want to avoid all application check.I want to apply sonar check only for modified files.

I want to run locally like mvn sonar:sonar

Thanks,
D Sahu

Comment: please be a little bit more specific about the "when" you gonna run it -> is this just for a CI or do you run it locally? if you run it locally is SonarLint an option to use?

Comment: I want to run locally like mvn sonar:sonar

Comment: Have you considered using SonarLint? It shows you issues as you code right in IDE. There are plugins available for most IDEs. https://www.sonarlint.org/  Another approach is to use filter functionality in SonarQube where you can filter by Creation Date, Author, etc. I personally prefer the latter approach as it doesn't require any special configurations and works just with mvn sonar:sonar. Here is a good link on different sonar checks: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE65/Local+and+Branch+Analysis

Comment: I am using sonar-lint, but I am looking some other way  so I can run from maven command.It capture only my changes made by my.